# Ways to talk about the last 3 hours

Tags: grammar, past-tense, present-perfect, idiomatic-language

Are all the following grammatical? and which one is the most natural?

> I haven't eaten anything **for** 3 hours.
>
> I haven't eaten anything **over** the last 3 hours.
>
> The last time I ate anything **was** 3 hours ago.

Comment: All are grammatical and idiomatic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are all natural, but you can omit the anything and just say:

> I haven't eaten for 3 hours.

I feel that is more idiomatic as it's something I've both said and heard many times living in Australia.